# Translate site name in multi language site

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

How can I translate site name for multi language site in drupal 8 ?

For Example:

> in site/en -> site name : Hello
>
> in site/fr -> site name : Bonjour

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it .

1 ) Install "Configuration Translation" module.

2 ) Go to "Basic site setting" ( admin/config/system/site-information )

3 ) Click "Translate system information" tab.

4 ) In front of your language click on "Add" button.

5 ) Then set your site name and click on "save translate" .